# Как сделать поворот div при нажатии на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Нужна помощь в реализации кнопки, которая будет плавно поворачивать `div` на 45 градусов. Необходимо учесть, что нажатие на кнопку может быть многократным.

```css
body {
  background-color: #888888;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px;
}
#superellips {
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #1eff00;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 40px;
}
#controls .button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 300px;
}
#controls .button:hover { background: rgba(255,255,255,.2); }
#controls .button:active { background: white; }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <title>Вращение суперэллипса</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <h1>Вращение суперэллипса</h1>
    <div id="superellips"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="controls">
    <button class="button" onclick="turnRight(this)">Повернуть по часовой стрелке</button>
    <button class="button" onclick="turnLeft()">Повернуть против часовой стрелки</button>
  </div>

  <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Пример кода](https://jsfiddle.net/vyzk3m2q/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function turnRight() {
  turnEllipse(45);
}

function turnLeft() {
  turnEllipse(-45);
}

function turnEllipse(degrees) {
  var angle = $("#superellips").data("angle");
  if (!angle)
    angle = 0;
  angle = +angle + degrees;
  $("#superellips")
    .data("angle", angle)
    .css({ transform: "rotate(" + angle + "deg)", transition: "1s" });
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #888888;
  color: #FFF;
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px;
}

#superellips {
  
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  background: #1eff00;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 40px;
}

#controls .button {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  user-select: none;
  padding: .5em 2em;
  outline: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 1px;
  transition: 0.2s;
  min-height: 50px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

#controls .button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
}

#controls .button:active {
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <h1>Вращение суперэллипса</h1>
  <div id="superellips"></div>
</div>

<div id="controls">
  <button class="button" onclick="turnRight()">Повернуть по часовой стрелке</button>
  <button class="button" onclick="turnLeft()">Повернуть против часовой стрелки</button>
</div>
```